# How to validate a form in a Jquery UI Dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, dialog, jquery-validate, validation

I'm trying to make a function to activate a 'form' for a 'field'.

```
function validacion_coment(form){
            $("#"+form).validate({

                    rules: {
                    texto: "required"
                },

                messages: {

                    texto: "<?php echo get_texto_clave('error_validate_empty'); ?>"
                }
            });
    }
```

But it doesn't, is there something special with validate() for dialog?

-edit- no error in Firebug.

WHEN I CALL IT

```
function nueva_respuesta(id){
$("#pop").load('./includes/router.php?que=nueva_respuesta&id='+id);
    pop_up_extra("pop","funcook.com",400,350);
    validacion_coment('respuesta');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What is form in the parameter list?  Can you post an example showing what you are passing into that parameter?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will bind the validation function to **all** of the forms on your page at pageload time.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('form').each(function() { 
      $(this).validate({
          rules: {
              texto: "required"
          },
          messages: {
              texto: "<?php echo get_texto_clave('error_validate_empty'); ?>"
          }
      });
  });

});
```

If you want to add validation for a **specific form**, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myIdOnMyForm').validate({
          rules: {
              texto: "required"
          },
          messages: {
              texto: "<?php echo get_texto_clave('error_validate_empty'); ?>"
          }
    });
});
```

**NOTE:** These events must be defined **before** you attempt to submit the form.  Pageload time is a good time to bind these events.

To bind the validation **after** loading HTML on the page, make sure the validation event setup is invoked in your AJAX load calback so that it doesn't try to bind it **before** the response has been received:

```
 $("#pop").load('./includes/router.php?que=nueva_respuesta&id='+id, function() {
    pop_up_extra("pop","funcook.com",400,350);
    validacion_coment('respuesta');
    return false;
 });
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the form doesn't exist yet when document.ready its called, that's why i want to make a function, to call it after loading the dialog

Comment: @Toni - It looks like you were invoking load possibly sequentially instead of calling your validation setup event in a callback handler.  Try this.